# Condition Variable with a while loop in thread in C++

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to figure out how to use `std::condition_variable` in C++ implementing a "strange" producer and consumer program in which I had set a limit to the `count` variable.

The main thread ("producer") increments the count and must wait for this to return to zero to issue a new increment.

The other threads enters in a loop where they have to decrease the counter and issue the notification.

I am blocked because it is not clear to me how to conclude the program by orderly exiting the while loop inside the function of all threads.

Could someone give me some guidance on how to implement it, please?

### Code

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <vector>

int main() {
        int n_core = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    std::vector<std::thread> workers;
    int max = 100;
    int count = 0;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::mutex mutex;
    int timecalled = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < n_core; i++) {
        workers.emplace_back(std::thread{[&max, &count, &mutex, &cv]() {
            while (true) {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk{mutex};
                std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " cv" << std::endl;
                cv.wait(lk, [&count]() { return count == 1; });
                std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " - " << count << std::endl;
                count--;
                std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " notify dec" << std::endl;
                cv.notify_all();
            }
        }});
    }

    while (max > 0) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk{mutex};
        std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " cv" << std::endl;
        cv.wait(lk, [&count]() { return count == 0; });
        std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " created token" << std::endl;
        count++;
        max--;
        timecalled++;
        std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " notify inc" << std::endl;

        cv.notify_all();
    }

    for (auto &w : workers) {
        w.join();
    }

    std::cout << timecalled << std::endl; // must be equal to max
    std::cout << count << std::endl; // must be zero

}
```

### Problem

The program doesn't end because it is stuck on some final `join`.

### Expected Result

The expected result must be:

```
100
0
```

### Edits Made

**EDIT 1** : I replaced `max > 0` in the while with a `true`. Now the loops are unbounded, but using the solution of @prog-fh seems to work.

**EDIT 2** : I added a variable to check the result in the end.

**EDIT 3**: I changed `while(true)` to `while(max >0)`. Could this be a problem in concurrency because we are reading it without a lock?

Comment: How do you tell the worker threads that they should exit? You need some way to do that. And you need a way that will work even when they're waiting on the CV.

Comment: The conditional statement predicate in the worker thread should also take into account `max` variable to terminate gracefully. Current predicate don't seem to make sense.

Comment: `max` is a shared resource - and you're not protecting it as you read it.  this is UB.  simplest fix is to replace the while with a "do while"; and then assign a local variable to the value of max while it's locked in the loop

Comment: Your second loop (the`main()`) should stop when `max` reaches zero (you just changed the condition and it is not the case any more).

Comment: @prog-fh The code is working without the condition variable in the main loop and `while(max >0)`. Could this be a problem in concurrency because we are reading it outside critical section? If yes I am thinking about a `while (true)` also for the main loop but with the trick used in the thread loop with condition variable.

Comment: You should avoid changing many things at once in your code, it becomes very difficult to follow. Starting from a well defined problem, to which I gave a solution (that seemed to solve your issue but that you didn't accept or upvote by the way) you totally changed it by modifying conditional tests, even removing a `cv.wait()` call... and you end up with something like  "what is wrong if I don't synchronise any more?". How can a previous answer still be relevant? How can we help you if your question changes every time?

Comment: But, from the version of your code that I can see now, if you consider my answer and if you uncomment the second `cv.wait()` call, you will obtain the expected result.

Comment: @prog-fh Sorry, I didn't want to cause confusion, but only provide an implementation of the code with the ability to check its correctness at the end. In any case, the code comment was my mistake (bad Copy&Paste from my local code). 

I would just like to understand if the fact that `max` is read outside the lock could cause race condition.

Ps. I cannot upvote (I have low reputation), but I will accept your solution at the end.

Comment: I edited my answer in order to clarity around the usage of `max`.

Comment: NEVER SET A CONDITION VARIABLE INSIDE A LOOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The threads are waiting for *something new* in the call `cv.wait()`.
But the only change that can be observed with the provided lambda-closure is the value of `count`.
The value of `max` must be checked too in order to have a chance to leave this `cv.wait()` call.

A *minimal* change in your code could be

```
cv.wait(lk, [&max, &count]() { return count == 1 || max<=0; });
if(max<=0) break;
```

assuming that changes to `max` always occur under the control of the mutex.

---

*An edit to clarify around the accesses to `max`.*

If the loop run by the threads is now `while(true)`, then the `max` variable is only read in its body which is synchronised by `mutex` (thanks to `lk`).
The loop run by the main program is `while (max > 0)`: `max` is read without synchronisation here but the only thread that can change this variable is the main program itself, so it's pure serial code from this perspective.
The whole body of this loop is synchronised by `mutex` (thanks to `lk`) so it is safe to change the value of `max` here since the read operations in the threads are synchronised in the same way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so I can use in general:
`cv.wait(lk, [&]() { return <condition waiting> || <condition_end_while>; });` followed by
`if(<condition_end_while>) break;` to block the while loop? Simple and plain solution, thanks!

Comment: @Piero Macaluso I wouldn't say that in general but in this very specific and simple case I think this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

1. You're having race conditions: in your code `max` may be read by multiple threads, whilst it is being modified in `main`, which is a race condition according to C++ standard.
2. The predicates you are using in `wait` seems to be incorrect (you're using `==`).